# Socket.io try get wrong url

Tags: node.js, socket.io, reveal.js

I'm trying to connect my reveal.js client and master presentations together using socket.io server.

I did all stuff, that Hakim Se describes on his github page, but socket.io still produces an error, while trying to connect to server.

```
GET http://0.0.7.156:8080/socket.io/1/?t=1393864538446 net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
```

If change 0.0.7.156 to my local machine name, query succeds.

I think I has wrong settings of presentations, but could not understand how to fix them.

Client:

```
multiplex: {
             secret: null, 
             id: 'a9e10bc1b02efafe',
             url: 'localname:1948' 
    },
```

Master:

```
multiplex: {
             secret: '13938623264068002486', 
             id: 'a9e10bc1b02efafe', 
             url: 'localname:1948'
    },
```

Comment: are you sure that this address 0.0.7.156:8080 exist and is active? It seems that the server is not responding.

Comment: this address is not working, but socket.io server is responding, because when go to port 1948, my presentation is working

Answer (score 3):

My experience has been that if I use `localhost`:

```
url: 'localhost:1948',
```

Something inside of reveal.js breaks and transforms `localhost` internally to the "nonsense" address `0.0.7.156` (bonus points to whoever digs into the code and finds the reason for this, I sadly currently do not have the time).  If I instead use `127.0.0.1`:

```
url: '127.0.0.1:1948',
```

Everything works just fine, at least locally for testing.

You will need to change `127.0.0.1` to whatever host name you will use when deploying the slides later on though.

Hope this helps!